# Faster way to match a string in MySQL using replace

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have an interesting problem trying to select rows from a table where there are multiple possibilities for a VARCHAR column in my where clause.

Here's my table (which has around 7 million rows):

```
CREATE TABLE `search_upload_detailed_results` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `surId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clei` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mfg` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cond` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fileId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nmId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quoteRequested` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sudr.surId` (`surId`),
  KEY `surd.clei` (`clei`),
  KEY `surd.pn` (`partNumber`),
  KEY `surd.fileId` (`fileId`),
  KEY `surd.price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm trying to match on the partNumber column. The problem is that the partNumber is in different formts, and can be entered in the search form in multiple formats.

Example: Part Number '300-1231-932' could be:

- 300-1231-932
- 3001231932
- 300 1231 932

A simple select like this takes 0.0008 seconds.

```
select avg(price) as price from search_upload_detailed_results where 
partNumber LIKE '3001231932%' and price > 0;
```

But it doesn't give me all of the matches that I need. So I wrote this query.

```
select avg(price) as price from search_upload_detailed_results 
where REPLACE(REPLACE(partNumber,'-',''),' ','') LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE('3001231932%','-',''),' ','') and price > 0;
```

This gives me all of the correct matches, but it's super slow at 3.3 seconds.

I played around with some things, trying to reduce the number of rows I'm doing the replace on, and came up with this.

```
select avg(price) as price from search_upload_detailed_results 
where price > 0 AND 
partNumber LIKE('300%') AND 
REPLACE(REPLACE(partNumber,'-',''),' ','') LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE('3001231932%','-',''),' ','');
```

It takes 0.4 seconds to execute. Pretty fast, but could still be a bit time consuming in a multi-part search.

I would like to get it a little faster, but this is as far as I could get. Are there any other ways to optimize this query?

UPDATE to show explain for the 3rd query:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, search_upload_detailed_results, range, surd.pn,surd.price, surd.pn, 103, , 89670, Using where
```

Comment: Why don't you canonicalize the part numbers in the table so they're always in the same format?

Comment: why don't you update this column and avoid issues in the future?

Comment: can you show a explain of the last query the one that takes 0.4 seconds to execute.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's hardly necessary. It's obvious that a query that compares two computed values can't use an index.

Comment: so? @Barmar Questions about queries performance should include a explain output in mine opion

Comment: Because it's a clear waste of time. There are some cases where you know a priori what it will say, and this is one of them. This query can't do anything but a full table scan.

Comment: "It's obvious that a query that compares two computed values can't use an index" @Barmar `partNumber LIKE('300%')` should atleast use the `surd.pn` key in some degree to narrow down the results... that's why i wanted to see the explain off that query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry, I didn't notice that part of the query. `EXPLAIN` shows that it's using the `pn` key, I guess there are lots of matches for that prefix so it's slow.

Comment: See explain in edit to original question. Barmar, the 3rd query doesn't have to do a full table scan. The first 2 parts of the WHERE clause cut it down to 89,670 rows.

Comment: Does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE partNumber LIKE '300%'` matche the rows output from the explain?  What does `EXPLAIN SELECT partNumber, REPLACE(REPLACE(partNumber,'-',''),' ','') AS partNumberFormatted FROM [table] WHERE partNumber LIKE '300%` output? ...  iám wondering about the last query it might be possible to write a delivered table approach if the last query is running fast and correctly optimized.. I believe the last query should use a covering index to fetch the results

Comment: The select count returns 84,849. A little less than the explain shows (89,670). Here is the explain for your query. Sorry for the format: # id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'search_upload_detailed_results', 'range', 'surd.pn', 'surd.pn', '103', NULL, '116453', 'Using where; Using index'

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to just store the part number with no extra characters in the table. Then remove these characters from the user input, and just do a simple `WHERE partnumber = @input` query.

If that's not possible, you can add that as an additional column. In MySQL 5.7 you can use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html); in earlier versions you can use a trigger that fills in this column.

Comment: Yes, that is the obvious answer, but it would take a lot of time to refactor the code and all of the tables that contain partNumber. I'll look into the generated column possibility.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get it a little faster, but this is as far as I could get. Are there any other ways to optimize this query?

As Barmar has said, the best solution if you really need speed (is 3.3s slow?) is to have a column with the untransformed data in it (hopefully now standardised), that'll allow you to query it without specifying all the different types of part numbers.

> Example: Part Number '300-1231-932' could be:
>
> 300-1231-932 ||
>     3001231932 ||
>    300 1231 932

I think you should worry about the presentation of your data, having all those different 'formats' will make it difficult - can you format to one standard (before it reaches the DB)?

> Here's my table (which has around 7 million rows):

Don't forget your index!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, the problem is the table format. If this is a non-negotiable then another alternative is:

If there are a few formats, but not too many, and they are well known (e.g. the three you've shown), then the query can be made to run faster by explicitly precalculating them all and searching for any of them.

```
select avg(price) as price from search_upload_detailed_results where 
partNumber IN ('300-1231-932', '3001231932', '300 1231 932')
```

This will take the best advantage of the index you presumably have on partNumber.

Comment: Unfortunately, re-engineering this very large application isn't in the cards right now. Your other solution wouldn't work either, because part numbers don't stop there. There are a lot of different versions of the same part (i.e. 300-1231-932-REV1, 300-1231-932-REV2, 300-1231-932-LN, etc.) Our searches need to return all of those parts.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that MySQL can make good use of the indexes for carefully selected regular expressions.

select avg(price) as price from search_upload_detailed_results where 
partNumber REGEXP '^300[- ]?1231[- ]?932';